# DataGrid in DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate with same ItemsSource (Current Item)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a problem with a DataGrid which is inside a DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate.

I have an ObservableCollection Classes which has about 20 properties but no other collections. I want to split them for better viewing. The first DataGrid called "mainGrid" should show the first 10 properties...

Then I have defined  DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate to show the rest if the user click on the row. But it doesn't work. The second DataGrid which is inside the RowDetailsTemplate

```
    <Dgv:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Dgv:DataGrid x:Name="dgvRowDetails">

                <Dgv:DataGrid.Columns>
                  <Dgv:DataGridTextColumn Header="Parameter 1" 
                               Binding="{Binding Parameter1}" />
                   <Dgv:DataGridTextColumn Header="Parameter 2" 
                               Binding="{Binding Parameter2}" />
                    </Dgv:DataGrid.Columns>
                </Dgv:DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Dgv:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

It displays only the headers in the RowDetails (when I click on a row) but no content.
The output tab doesn't show any binding errors.

I think I need a ItemsSource, too but I don't know how to realise it because the other properties refer to the current or selectedItem.

But this e.g works fine:

```
    <Dgv:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Parameter1}" />
          <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Parameter2}" />
         </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Dgv:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

But I really want a DataGrid because of Headers etc...

I am using .NET 3.5

Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do this. `ItemsSource` expects to be an `IEnumerable` and what you want is to give it a single item.

This is sort of a hacky way to accomplish it. In your object's class that you bind the outer datagrid's ItemSource to define a new property that returns itself in the form of some `IEnumerable`

```
public class MyClass
{
    public IEnumerable<MyClass> AsIEnumerable
    {
        get
        {
            yield return this;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
//Inner datagrid
//Datacontext is MyClass object
<Dgv:DataGrid x:Name="dgvRowDetails" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding AsIEnumerable}">
    <Dgv:DataGrid.Columns>
       <Dgv:DataGridTextColumn Header="Parameter 1" 
                               Binding="{Binding Path=Parameter1}" />
       <Dgv:DataGridTextColumn Header="Parameter 2" 
                               Binding="{Binding Path=Parameter2}" />
    </Dgv:DataGrid.Columns>
</Dgv:DataGrid>
```

You say you want headers. My recommendation is to create headers with the proper tools, not shoehorn squares into circles because circles exist.

Comment: Hey Shoe, thank you so much. Your 'hack' does work. But because of the yield you cannot use an ObservableCollection so I can't modify the values in the DataGrid. Nevertheless, I have spent some time and have created my own "DataGrid" withlabels and textboxes. Now I have the best control and flexibility. But thank you anyways!

Comment: You dont have to use yield return. You can build a new ObservableCollection and return `this` added to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <Dgv:DataGrid x:Name="dgvRowDetails" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

Comment: Hey ethicallogics, thanks for your post, but that doesn't work.